# Is it possible to use port knocking with autoSSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

How do I use port knocking with autoSSH?

My current solution is to run the script -

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
        knock myhomecomputer.com 64001 && sleep 1 && knock myhomecomputer.com 64002 && sleep 1 && knock myhomecomputer.com 64003 && sleep 1 && knock myhomecomputer.com 64004
        ssh -R 65522:localhost:22 myhomecomputer.com
done
```

The above script is placed in the crontab as -

```
@reboot screen -dmS reverseSSH /home/user_me/reverse_ssh_4_myhomecomputer
```

How is such a script different from autoSSH? What additional cases does autoSSH handle?

The idea is to have the above script or autoSSH run on my lab machine behind by university firewall so I can SSH into it from home. My home computer faced a huge amount of brute force SSH attacks, so I had to put it behind a knock sequence activated firewall. Is there a better way to handle this?

The above script works and I can ssh into the university computer using the following command on my home computer -

```
ssh -p 65522 localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got around the problem

1. I edited the `~/.ssh/config` on the lab machine to add the following

   ```
   host myhomecomputer.com
       HostName myhomecomputer.com
       user user_me
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user_me.openSSH

   host myhomecomputer
       HostName myhomecomputer.com
       user user_me
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user_me.openSSH
       ProxyCommand bash -c 'source knock_myhomecomputer_ssh; ssh -TN -R 65522:localhost:22 myhomecomputer.com'
   ```

   Notice the names - `myhomecomputer` (alias / shortcut)  & `myhomecomputer.com` (actual host).
2. The `knock_myhomecomputer_ssh` is as -

   ```
   SLEEP_T=0.75
   knock myhomecomputer.com 64001 && sleep $SLEEP_T && knock myhomecomputer.com 64002 && sleep $SLEEP_T && knock myhomecomputer.com 64003 && sleep $SLEEP_T && knock myhomecomputer.com 64004
   ```
3. Added the following to my `crontab`

   ```
   @reboot autossh -f myhomecomputer
   ```